# SwiftUI Stroke Colour and Width?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, stroke

I am following Apples "[Creating and Combining View](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views#combine-views-using-stacks)" SwiftUI Tutorial and on Section 4 Step 5 I am asked to add a Gray Stroke, which I can do but doesn't show the colour or give me a line width.

```
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle().stroke(StrokeStyle))
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of bug?

As Apples example shows;

```
           .clipShape(Circle())
           .overlay(
               Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 4))
```

I can type it in but don't understand why it is not pulling the colour from the Inspector.  I can even amend the colour from Gray to White but again I cannot see this referenced in the code

Also is it possible to add/set a lineWidth from the Inspector?  The next step with adding the shadow made perfect sense but this step has really stumped me.

Answer (score 4):

The `stroke(...)` function of `Circle()` is overloaded multiple times.

> function overloading or method overloading is the ability to create
>   multiple functions of the same name with different implementations.

You can read about function overloading here: [Function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)

Heres the Documentation of the four different implementations of `stroke(...)`

[stroke(style:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/circle/3363474-stroke)

[stroke(lineWidth:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/circle/3363473-stroke)

[stroke(_:style:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/circle/3363472-stroke)

[stroke(_:lineWidth:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/circle/3363470-stroke)

all of them are valid and you can decide which one you use or which one best suits your needs.

```
Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)  
Circle().stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, lineCap: .butt, lineJoin: .bevel, miterLimit: 1, dash: [CGFloat](), dashPhase: 1))
```

Both of this implementations do the same but are using different implementations of the stroke(...) function.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean color literals, then they are `UIColor` type, so you have to wrap them explicitly in `Color` constructor, like below

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Circle()
.stroke(.gray.opacity(0.2),lineWidth: 4)
```